# capturing mouse event in C (linux)

Tags: c, linux, mouseevent

I'm writing a little mouselogger in basic C for linux.
I search mouse event in linux/input.h, but I have not found anything about this.

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    __u16 type;
    __u16 code;
    __s32 value;
}
```

With the `struct input_event`, I can capturing which button was pressed on mouse and when she move, but not his position.
( I separate the field value in two  __s16 variable, but is not a position).

If anyone know a structure where I can access this, or a specific file to listen (actually I'm listen `/dev/input/event6`)...

Thank, bye !

Comment: Are you using some sort of GUI (X-Windows, GTK etc), or are you wanting to do this in a CUI (text, tty)?

Comment: I'm not using a GUI , if I can, I prefer in a CUI

Comment: You get multiple events per movement/action: one event per axis -- I describe the format for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38199899/1475978) --, followed by an `EV_SYN,SYN_REPORT` event that ends the group of events that occurred simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.microcontrollertips.com/using-input-devices-on-embedded-linux-usb-mouse-on-intel-edison/) gives you step by step guidance on how do to exactly what you want.